# Erro ao instalar pip install mod-wsgi-httpd

Tags: python, apache, flask, pip

Estou tentando instalar o pacote mod-wsgi-httpd atraves do comando pip, mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
...
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Downloading http://www.us.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-1.5.1.tar.gz
```

Eu coloquei só o final do erro, e da para reparar que ele tenta baixar um arquivo e não encontra, eu naveguei até a url: http://www.us.apache.org/dist/apr/ no navegador em busca do arquivo apr-1.5.1.tar.gz mas não existe mais, a menor versão lá é a 1.6.5.

Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível contornar esse problema?

Estou tentando fazer isso pois quero fazer o deploy de uma api flask para rodar no windows com apache.

Comment: Achei esse arquivo aqui: https://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/ Agora como vai fazer pra instalar eu não sei